# How to plot with regular-space sampling?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a simple square function wave, like this:

```
Plot[Table[f[x_] = If[(n - 0.1) <= x <= (n + 0.1), 1, 0], {n, 0, 100, 1}], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

This looks no problem.

But once I extend the x-axis limit to 100, the plot becomes irregular.

```
Plot[Table[f[x_] = If[(n - 0.1) <= x <= (n + 0.1), 1, 0], {n, 0, 100, 1}], {x, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

I think this is caused by Mathematica not sampling the data points in regular x-spacing.

Is there anyone know how to plot the periodic function correctly, so that it preserves the regularity of the wave shape?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Increase the `PlotPoints` setting.

Comment: Also, you should remove the `f[x_] = ` part from the expression, as this will result in unnecessary definitions for `f` and decrease performance.

Comment: I have try increasing PlotPoints. It looks better, but it is not sampling with exactly regular spacing.@J.M.

Comment: `PlotPoints -> 1000` produces a nice graph.  Most of the plotting functions do not do strictly regular sampling. Regular sampling (see MikeY's answer) will miss at least one of the corners at the discontinuities. Is that what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is primarily to get a good picture, you can use your knowledge of the function you are plotting and can rig up your own sampling using ListPlot[ ]. First define a better $f[x]$

```
    f[x_] := If[Abs[Round[x] - x] <= 0.1, 1, 0];
```

Then you can set a sampling interval $d$ to get the resolution you want...

```
    d=.001;
    ListPlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 10, d}], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

```
    ListPlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 50, d}], Joined -> True]
```

[image]